# Can I use scaffold yeoman over an existing project?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, yeoman

I have a clutter of files comprising my node/express/angular app. I want to build a more structured directory structure.

1.
Can I do this with Yeoman, now after we are 6 months into developing our app and if so, how?

2.
What are the benefits aside from the cleaner structure?

Answer (score 0):

You can happily use Yeoman. I would recommend you to use Yeoman along with Grunt. I suits best you to build the minification process and removes the overhead of upgrading versions manually.

Comment: Can you outline what will happen if I `yo` over my project?

Answer (score 0):

Yeoman generators are much better suited for ground-up development. That being said, you can potentially retrofit your exiting app to use one of the generators (maybe [this one](https://www.npmjs.org/package/generator-angular-fullstack)), but you'd be much better off running the generator in a new directory and then plugging in your existing code.